# C# inherited field value getting mixed up with base class' field value

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, properties, hierarchy

I'm trying to serialize instances of 'MyClass' into an XML file, one at a time. Each instance has an int property called 'ID'. The target file already has some items of the same type, and I'm appending the new items after those. I would like the to-be-inserted instance's ID value to be 1 higher than the largest existing item in the XML.

I have the following generic class:

```
public class ContentDataManager<T> where T : MyBaseClass
{
    private static string _contentLocation = "Content/Data/";
    private const string DEFAULT_FILEPATH = "data.xml";

    public static int GetNextId(string filepath = DEFAULT_FILEPATH)
    {
        var allData = DeserializeAll(filepath);
        int largestId = 0;
        foreach (T data in allData)
        {
            if (data.ID > largestId)
            {
                largestId = data.ID;
            }
        }
        return largestId + 1;
    }
//...
}
```

I'm using this class like this:

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public string Name;
    public float Size;
    public new int ID;

    public static MyClass CreateNew(string name, float size)
    {
        MyClass newClass = new MyClass();
        newClass.Name = name;
        newClass.Size = size;
        newClass.ID = ContentDataManager<MyClass>.GetNextId(DefaultFilepath);
        return newClass;
    }
```

MyBaseClass looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    //...
    [ContentSerializerIgnore]
    public int ID = 0;
}
```

The problem is, that in the ContentDataManager.GetNextId(...) method's foreach loop, there's an if statement that actually doesn't work properly. When I was debugging, I added two watches: 'data' and 'data.ID'
Here comes the interesting part: **The watch for 'data' shows that the ID property's value is 1. At the sime time, the 'data.ID' property shows a value of 0.**

I'm pretty sure this error is related to inheritance. How should I change my code, so that I don't get this error?

Comment: Why are you hiding the `ID` from `MyBaseClass` in your `MyClass` using the `new` operator? That variable is public and inherited by your `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove this line:

```
public new int ID;
```

From what you shown there is no need for a separate ID in the derived class, the base one will do just fine. Of course you will need to removed the `ContentSerializerIgnore` attribute too if you want ID to be serialized.

Here is an example to demonstrate, that when you use the 'new' keyword for declaring a member you create completely unrelated member to the base class member.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    abstract class  Base
    {
        public string Data;
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        // this is a separate field, has nothing in common with the base class field but name
        new public string Data;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Derived test = new Derived();

            //Let's set the Data field in the derived class
            test.Data = "Derived";

            //Now let's set this field in the base class
            Base cast = test;
            cast.Data = "Base";

            //We can see that the feild in the derived class has not changed
            //This will print 'Derived'
            Console.WriteLine(test.Data);

            // Just to make sure that a new object has not been constructed by a miracale
            // let's pass our object to a function that will display the Data field from
            // the base class
            Test(test);
        }

        static void Test(Derived test)
        {
            // When called from the Main above this will print 'Base'
            Console.WriteLine(((Base)test).Data);            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem. The hiding was a leftover, from when I was trying different approaches. Works perfectly after the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've specified `where T : MyBaseClass`. And that means the `data` foreach loop variable will be of type `MyBaseClass`.  So the only accessible value of `data.ID` will be the base class's version.

[See this write-up about it.](http://www.kowitz.net/archive/2006/10/31/the-public-new-overridden-int-id)

You'll have to either type cast `data` to be type `MyClass` or always use the base class `ID` field (which is what [zespri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073200/12570) suggests).

Comment: Thanks for the link, C# is beautiful :-)